# IELTS Reading passage issue (English as a foreign language learner I am)

Tags: reading, ielts

I have been taking IELTS mock exams recently on a website. (The tests are probably taken from Cambridge textbooks).

So I have 2 points I may disagree with in the Reading section.

I had to choose whether certain statements TRUE, FALSE or NOT GIVEN

Question 19 statement says **China has more citrus pests than any other country in the world.**

I chose **NOT GIVEN**

And in the text it goes like this:

*Citrus fruits evolved in the Far East and the Chinese discovered the delights of their flesh early on. As the ancestral home of oranges, lemons and pomelos, **China also has the greatest diversity of citrus pests.** And the trees that produce the sweetest fruits, the mandarins - or kan - attract a host of plant-eating insects, from black ants and sap-sucking mealy bugs to leaf-devouring caterpil­lars. With so many enemies, fruit growers clearly had to have some way of pro­tecting their orchards.*

While the authors of this website say that the correct answer should be TRUE, and referring to the sentence in bold in the quote as a proof.

---

My position of understanding is as follows:

Statement 1: China has more citrus pests than any other country in the world.

Statement 2: China also has the greatest DIVERSITY of citrus pests.

Two statements don't carry same meaning for following reasons:

Let's say, China has the greatest DIVERSITY of citrus pests, like 10 TYPES of citrus pests. Assume 10 is the highest number of DIVERSITY in the world. But, there is one citrus pest of each type in China. How many pests we will have in total? 10!

On the other hand, let's say England has only one TYPE of citrus pests. England has a hundred of citrus pests of ONE TYPE only.

On diversity levels, China has greater number of pests than England has, sure. But when it comes to overall amount of citrus pests, regardless of their diversity, England has it more than China.

So the problem is: Q19 says "China has more citrus pests than any other country in the world." NOT MORE DIVERSE

---

As long as I understand, the answer should be NOT GIVEN.

WHat should the correct answer be -- TRUE, FALSE, or NOT GIVEN?

Comment: Disagree. You have to use some common sense in tests like this. *More pests* can refer to the total number of individuals, but it can also mean *more types of pest*. Many sentences are ambiguous if you approach them like Dr Spock, and the ability to resolve that kind of ambiguity is an aspect of the reading skillset they are testing here.

Comment: @Minty I would upvote if you expanded and transferred your comment into an answer.

Comment: If this test is supposed to test one's ability to read **carefully** (in manner one does when studying, say, a textbook in a scientific discipline), rather than one's ability to **guess** what somebody **may** have had in mind (but did not actually say), then the OP is perfectly right: the diversity of pests is only a matter of how many species of pests there are, and not of the total number of pests. Admittedly the words *host* and *many* in the following sentences do imply that the number of pests is high, but they do not imply that it is higher than in any other country.

Comment: The OP should note that agree-or-disagree questions are not well suited to the Stack Exchange format. In response to such a question, one may wish to say simply 'Yeah, you are right', but posting that as an answer would be frowned upon on Stack Exchange. An agree-or-disagree question may thus end up without a formally posted answer, even though it is sensible, well thought-out, and otherwise within the scope of this site.

Comment: Can you say what number book, e.g. IELTS 7 (which is in a series of exam prep books) or the title of the coursebook the reading passage came from? Thanks. **EDIT**. I found what I think is the source http://mini-ielts.com/1056/reading/the-ant-and-the-mandarin The site is NOT affiliated with Cambridge and on its homepage, it says *Simulate real tests*. The IELTS exam books help candidates prepare using *past* exam material. Beware of sites that are not supported by Cambridge or the British Council.

Comment: @jsw29 The source of the reading test appears to be from [IELTS online tests.com](https://ieltsonlinetests.com/ielts-online-practice-tests-free) and it says: *Real IELTS Listening and IELTS Reading tests based on actual IELTS tests and ***following the Cambridge IELTS book format***. Again, not supported by Cambridge. As a resource and for practice purposes this is probably fine, it's free and it helps candidates to prepare  but it is not the original Cambridge material, so it's likely there will be errors.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, does this mean that you agree with the OP, after all? Your first comment seems to imply the opposite.

Comment: @jsw29 it was really meant as a spur and besides, there was an element of truth in what Minty said.

Comment: These tests are notoriously flaky.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tests which require a "true / false / not given" answer should not be ambiguous, nor should they require students to make assumptions...

If the examiners wanted to know what students could "infer" from the given text, they would not have asked for a "true / false / not given" answer.

A person's ability to differentiate between "most diverse" & "most numerous" is a credit to their understanding of the language & to their intelligence...

Teachers who put ambiguous questions in "yes / no" type tests are either ignorant or sadistic.

Regarding the question quoted by Isakov-U, the correct answer would be (/ should be) "not given".